# Simulating a mouse button click in Windows

Tags: qt, button, mouse, click, simulate

I'm writing Remote Desktop clone in C++ using QT. So far I'm able to move the mouse cursor around fine. QT has a nice setPos function for that. However, I'm a bit lost as to what API/Library to use for simulating mouse button clicks.

One method I'm aware of is to send the WM_(event) to a window using the window's HWND. However, I was hoping there was a more salient method for taking complete control over a mouse. Is there any other way to tell the operating system that the left mouse button has been clicked?

Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nick. How did you succeed with your remote desktop? I'm currently extending an application with remote support. I wonder, how did you solve text input in text components (if at all)? It's easy to recognize in Qt, whether a widget under the cursor is a QLineEdit or the like. But what to do for native Windows objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is in C#, but might help you to get an idea:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll",CharSet=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention=CallingConvention.StdCall)]
   public static extern void mouse_event(long dwFlags, long dx, long dy, long cButtons, long dwExtraInfo);

   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN = 0x02;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP = 0x04;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTDOWN = 0x08;
   private const int MOUSEEVENTF_RIGHTUP = 0x10;

   public void DoMouseClick()
   {
      int X = Cursor.Position.X;
      int Y = Cursor.Position.Y;
      mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, X, Y, 0, 0);
   }
```

**Resources which might help:**

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646260%28VS.85%29.aspx

http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/W-P/win32/article.php/c4543/

Answer (score 9):

Combining all togegher, here is the code for Qt:

```
#include <windows.h>
QApplication::desktop()->cursor().setPos(globalX,globalY);
mouse_event(MOUSEEVENTF_ABSOLUTE | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN | MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP, 1, 1, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Lukas Šalkauskas' solution has worked for me for quite some time, but today it suddenly resulted in the following error (perhaps due to some .NET update by Windows Update?)

> A call to PInvoke function
>   'SampleMethod' has unbalanced the
>   stack.  This is likely because the
>   managed PInvoke signature does not
>   match  the unmanaged target signature.
>   Check that the calling convention and 
>   parameters of the PInvoke signature
>   match the target unmanaged signature.

So I switched to the [pinvoke.net sample code](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.mouse_event) and it works well now:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);

[Flags]
public enum MouseEventFlags
{
    LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
    LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
    MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
    MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
    MOVE = 0x00000001,
    ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
    RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
    RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
}

public static void LeftClick(int x, int y)
{
    Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```