# Simulate Mouse Click and Mouse Move in Windows 7 using C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have written a piece of code to simulate mouse click which is working fine in my Vista. But when I tested that in windows 7 its not generating the click event. Could some one please help? I am adding the code snippet below.
Thanks,
Nikil

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern void mouse_event(int dwFlags, int dx, int dy, int dwData, int dwExtraInfo);


[Flags]
        public enum MouseEventFlags
        {
            LEFTDOWN = 0x00000002,
            LEFTUP = 0x00000004,
            MIDDLEDOWN = 0x00000020,
            MIDDLEUP = 0x00000040,
            MOVE = 0x00000001,
            ABSOLUTE = 0x00008000,
            RIGHTDOWN = 0x00000008,
            RIGHTUP = 0x00000010
        }

System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Hide();
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(xinc + rct.Left, yinc + rct.Top);

int X = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.X;
int y = System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position.Y;

mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);


System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 0);
System.Windows.Forms.Cursor.Show();
```

Comment: mouse_event has been completely superceded by SendInput.  Does your code work if updated to SendInput?

Comment: @Michael : HI Could you please provide an example or link to use send input in c#?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My crystal ball says you didn't just upgrade to Win7, you also got the 64-bit version.  Previously you had the 32-bit version of Vista.  Your mouse_event() declaration is wrong.  The last argument is IntPtr, not int.

How did the ball do?

Comment: That's odd, the exact same sig he uses works well for me: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740045/simulating-a-mouse-button-click-in-windows/3002585#3002585

Comment: @ohadsc - the pinvoke.net link is all over the place, using both IntPtr and int.  Your declaration can only work on the 32-bit version of Windows *or* Windows Mobile.  The latter which documents it as an int.  Which is okay, there will never be a 64-bit version of it.  Maybe there's a good reason this function got deprecated :)

Comment: The marked answer in that thread is stunningly wrong.  Nobody can get that going, no matter what OS they use.  Maybe they passed a lot of zeros.

Comment: Yeah, I have moved from 32 bit to 64 bit. I think thats the problem. Could you please tell how to rewrite the above one for a 64bit version. Also I have checked the error you mentioned but I found two ways of doing it here http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/mouse_event.html?diff=y Could you please help?

Comment: Patting the ball, good job.  As I said, change the type of the dwExtraInfo argument from int to IntPtr.  Pass IntPtr.Zero in the call.

Comment: @Hans I wasn't referring to the marked answer in that thread, rather to my answer, which works on at least two win7 / 64 machines that I can remember

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will help you, but have you looked at UI Automation?
[link text](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms753107%28v=VS.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

A trick that has worked for me is using [SetCursorPos](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/setcursorpos.html) with the same coordinate before the `mouse_event` call. I've also just verified the following to work (on winforms):

```
    public static void LeftClick(int x, int y)
    {
        Cursor.Position = new System.Drawing.Point(x, y); //<= fails without this
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTDOWN), 0, 0, 0, 0);
        mouse_event((int)(MouseEventFlags.LEFTUP), 0, 0, 0, 0);
    }
```