# What is the "mouse" equivalent to System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys?

Tags: .net, winforms, io

I'm looking for a .NET class that will do what SendKeys does, but for mouse input.
Thanks!

Comment: This seems to be been already asked/answered [Simulate Mouse Click and Mouse Move in Windows 7 using C#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650532/simulate-mouse-click-and-mouse-move-in-windows-7-using-c-sharp)

Comment: @algirdas: from the question you referenced "mouse_event has been completely superceded by SendInput. Does your code work if updated to SendInput?" So yes, it does come to the same conclusion, but not as quickly or as clearly-stated. I wanted to make sure I had a solid answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use [that](http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/) open source project about simulating mouse or keyboard.

Comment: promising project, but it appears to only support keyboard input for now

Comment: SendInput is ultimately the best way to do this that I am aware of. I just don't want to have to make the ugly API calls. If the C# wrapper can encapsulate both keyboard and mouse input, that'd be fantastic. Additionally it simulates keypresses, not just text entry so it's 100% simulated I/O

Comment: +1 Disregard my last comment; I had read the notes for the first release. I just downloaded the project and tested it; the mouse input works.

Comment: @w0lf +2 Thanks for the help! :) I was worried I'd have to update the project myself to add the mouse functionality. I was looking at the source at the same time you added your second comment, and came to roughly the same conclusion.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that through System.Windows.Forms that I am aware of.  I have had some success with [mouse_event](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/mouse_event.html)

Comment: +1 This is really good to know! Not quite the best the answer to my question, but thank you anyway. :)