# Is it possible in Qt to move the mouse and make it "click" anywhere on screen?

Tags: qt

Title says it all! My program should run in background and sometimes move to a coordinate and do a mousepress. I can move the mouse, but I can't make it click. Is it possible somehow?

Comment: what do you want to do by click?

Comment: You need to click in your own program or some other window? Windows, Linux or Mac?

Comment: I want it to work in an other window on Windows 7.

Comment: @AB, will this help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740045/simulating-a-mouse-button-click-in-windows?lq=1 ?